# Coroutine Flow is paused when the app is in the background

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

The problem that I'm trying to resolve is to make a `flow` living as long as a specific scope eg. `viewModelScope`. Look at this simple example where a flow is printing continuously logs in the while loop.

```
class TestViewModel : ViewModel(){
    init {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            flow<Unit> {
                while (true) {
                    delay(1000L)
                    Log.e("livingWhile", "tick")
                }
            }.collect()
        }
    }
}
```

Everything is working perfect (I'm receving a log every second) until the app is put to the background (block button), then after like 1-2 minutes when the app is in the background stops printing logs. Looks like something paused my scope and I'm not sure what and why. Few considerations - the app is not killed, viewmodel is living (`onCleared` not called yet), flow not called `onCompletion` yet,  the while loop just stops. It starts to looping again when the app is bring back to the foreground.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Do specify what device/emulator and their version of android you're experiencing this on.

Comment: @Pawel OnePlus 6T Android 11

Comment: Have you tried disabling battery optimizations for your app? I'm suspecting that, once you disable all batery optimizations for your app, the logs will just keep on coming regardless if you're in background or not. Especially on OnePlus (and few others) phones.

Comment: This is expected behavior. Android is designed to discourage continually running code in the background using up battery and adding jank to the main thread. If you need to run code when your app is in the background, read about [background tasks](https://developer.android.com/guide/background). But your example above does something every second, so it would need a Foreground Service, not a background task.

Comment: @Tenfour04 A foreground service seems to [not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76446935/coroutine-launched-from-foreground-service-getting-paused) be enough to prevent a coroutine from getting paused.

Comment: @BPDev I believe you have to call `goAsync` in your service for it to stay alive for other threads. I’m rusty on this and away from computer so cannot conveniently search. But I wrote an answer about a year ago or so on the topic of going async with a coroutine in a service.